BULK COLLECT fetching and inserting all records from table even condition are mention for a specific range
I am creating a script for migration where I have to insert a million of records from one table to another table but with condition (like insertion for one table to another table for last year). But below code fetching all records  instead of last year records.
   v_source_count_sql:='SELECT COUNT(1)   FROM '||source_table_name ||' WHERE  '||archive_date_col ||' between '
   ||''''||to_date(archive_form_date,'dd-mm-yyyy')||''''||' and '||''''||to_date(archive_to_date,'dd-mm-yyyy')||'''';
   EXECUTE IMMEDIATE v_source_count_sql into v_source_count_sql;
   DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(v_source_count_sql);
--      v_source_sql:='SELECT a.rowid ,a.*  FROM '||source_table_name ||' a '||'  WHERE  a.'||archive_date_col ||' between '
--      ||''''||to_date(archive_form_date,'dd-mm-yyyy')||''''||' and '||''''||to_date(archive_to_date,'dd-mm-yyyy')||'''';
    v_source_sql:=q'[SELECT a.rowid ,a.*  FROM PRM_MASTER a   WHERE  a.CTRCT_DATE between '01-01-23' and '01-12-23']';--4 rows
   DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line(v_source_sql);
   EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 
                'DECLARE 
                TYPE source_table_collection IS TABLE OF ' || source_table_name || '%ROWTYPE;
                source_data source_table_collection;
                BEGIN
--                  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE '||v_source_sql||' BULK COLLECT into source_data;
                END; ';



CTRCT_DATE between '01-01-23' and '01-12-23' would only work if your nls_date_format is DD-MM-RR. It defaults to DD-MON-RR but can be overridden. Always convert strings to dates using explicit TO_DATE functions with a format model so it is interpreted as you expect. Also, a.rowid,a.* isn't going to be fetchable into a table of type a%rowtype, because that wouldn't include the rowid.

ya I already converted  into date . if you see there are 2 v_source_sql variables. the variable which hold this query q'[SELECT a.rowid ,a.*  FROM PRM_MASTER a   WHERE  a.CTRCT_DATE between '01-01-23' and '01-12-23']' comes from first v_source_sql and also to date is there.

By default Oracle will allow month numbers where names/abbreviations are expected, but it's still bad practice to rely on that or implicit conversion or NLS settings. You are already outputting v_source_sql; also output the whole dynamic anonymous block so you can see what that ends up as. As PaulW said your collection looks wrong and that block will error anyway - at the moment because there is no actual statement between its begin/end... Why are you using a collection at all, rather than insert into <target> select ...?

@PaulW Oracle's default DATE format depends on the NLS_TERRITORY settings - if the database thinks you are in Algeria, Bahrain, India, Morocco, The Netherlands or Tunisia then the default is DD-MM-RR. (But, regardless, relying on implicit conversions is not good practice - because if someone in Japan ran the query their default date format is RR-MM-DD and days and years would be swapped.)
